# Python array to Image, over 255

Tags: python, arrays, image, python-imaging-library, opencv

I want to save array that array's element is over 255 to image file (.jp2). Data type is 'int32'.  Is there any method to save array to image that array's element is over 255? This is used for processing sentinel-2 datasets.

I already tried it with `cv2`, `pil`, `scipy` functions. 
but it doesn't work.

-
`imwrite`, `scipy.misc.toimage`, `scipy.misc.imsave`, `.save()`...
I already tried these functions..

For example, `h_01` array is like this.

```
[[1419.  1448.5 1444.  ... 1388.5 1390.5 1391.5]

[1449.5 1434.  1448.  ... 1370.  1372.  1373. ]

[1424.5 1428.5 1457.  ... 1353.5 1354.5 1378. ]

...

[1430.  1412.5 1422.5 ... 1500.  1474.5 1495. ]

[1449.5 1409.5 1417.5 ... 1472.5 1492.  1512.5]

[1447.5 1429.  1437.  ... 1492.  1511.5 1509.5]]
```

and I changed my data to `int32`.

`h_01=np.array(h_01,np.int32)`

then, I save this array to image

`scipy.misc.toimage(h_01).save(opt.image+"_01.jp2")`

in this method, array saved like this.

```
[[28 33 32 ... 23 23 23]

[33 31 33 ... 20 20 20]

[29 30 34 ... 17 17 21]

...

[30 27 28 ... 42 37 41]

[33 26 28 ... 37 40 44]

[33 30 31 ... 40 44 43]]
```

I want to save array that element is over 255 to image file(.jp2). 
but it doesn't work, results that saved are not over 255 (have loss).

Comment: PIL supports `"I"` and `"F"` [mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) images with 32-bit pixels, but not the JP2 image file format. Few image libraries I know of support it. Is that image file format a requirement?

Comment: I have to save images as jp2 format.. but i will try "I" and "F" !! thankyou !

Comment: I can't seem to get this done by **PIL**, nor **pyvips**, nor **Wand**...